# Batch rename Tracks in iTunes

Tags: itunes, windows

I am using iTunes on a Windows 7 system. Is there an easy way to bath rename the tracks?

I have an audio book I am importing and it is fine but I want to make sure the tracks stay in order and the names provided by iTunes are inconsistent. I want to name them like

1. Track 1
2. Track 2
3. Track 3
4. etc.

I have seen ways to do this on a mac but how on a Windows System?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using a managed library, naming files is pretty much irrelevant. Instead of renaming files, you should be able to correct this consistent metadata.

As long as the files are named with the same Album, and the track/disc numbers are laid out accordingly, the files will be played in order.

Consider the following:

[image: Poorly Laid Out Tracks, Compared to an ordered set]

As you can see, I have one album in perfect track order, and a recently added Audiobook in total disarray.

Screw renaming files! iTunes does that for you anyway. Mass-edit all the consistent tags first.

[image: iTunes Metadata Editing Screen]

Grouping them by total number of tracks, disc, album, and artist, will organize them all into their own section initially. After doing so it's a simple matter of clicking on a single track, entering it's specific track number, and clicking next.

The coolest part of this process it that iTunes will maintain focus in the metadata field you select, so once you have everything else out of the way, simply leave the mouse cursor on the 'Next' button, type a track number which you should be able to get from the track name, then tap on the mouse button without moving it.

Two minutes later, you have consistent metadata:

[image: Audiobook tracks now consistent]

Comment: And yes, I do have an album whose track names consists of "One", "Two", and "Three", in that order. And it's an AWESOME album too.

Answer (score 1):

To my knowledge there is no way to do it in iTunes itself, but I use a great program called MP3tag for renaming batch audio files.

http://www.mp3tag.de/en/